# Regular Expression for deleting all datetimes from conversation

Tags: regex, swift

I have string with new lines in swift like this:

How can I remove all timestamps(11.03.2016 22:46:16) from that string ?

Answer (score 0):

Simplest one for your situation could be search with following regex and replace with `empty string`.

**Regex:** `^[\d.: ]+:` and replace with `empty string`.

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fI1vF0/2)**

Comment: You see the line with `evet daha mantıklı` in your approach? It matches the `:D` as well. Bind it to the beginning!

Comment: @Jan: Done ! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach would be a character class combined with anchors:

```
^[\d. :]+(.+)
# anchor it to the beginning of the line
# only digits, spaces, dots and a colon allowed
# one or more times
# the (.+) brings you down the line
```

Take only the first captured group here.
See a demo for this approach <kbd>[here on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/tW1uX1/1)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

The most accurate solution with the fewest false matches would be this:

`^\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{4} \d{2}.\d{2}.\d{2}:`

You'll want to use the regex multiline and global flags too.